# nmap using --script-args for scripts

Tags: wordpress, nmap

Trying to figure out how to use script-args with nmap.  Trying to use the http-wordpress-brute script to test against my own WP install, but reviewing the documentation here: https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-wordpress-brute.html, I cannot figure out how to specify the user/password list.

Output:

```
root@kali:~# nmap -p80 --script-args 'userdb=testuser,passdb=passwordlist.txt,http-wordpress-brute' domain.com

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-08-17 00:26 EDT
Nmap scan report for domain.com (90.10.784.854)
Host is up (0.021s latency).
rDNS record for 90.10.784.854: host.domain.com
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.22 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding `-d` to your command to get debugging output. Probably the script is not detecting the Wordpress login form. You may have to provide the URI path to `wp-login.php` via the `uri` script-arg. It's also possible that the form detection doesn't work with the version of Wordpress you have installed.

If you upgrade to Nmap 7.10 or later, you can try the [improved `http-form-brute`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-form-brute.html) script. You'll still have to tell it which URI path to attack, but it should do much better at detecting and dealing with unusual login forms and CSRF tokens.

EDIT: I noticed you are not using the `--script` option. You must select the script to run via `--script` and provide arguments via `--script-args`. Your example would be correctly run as:

```
nmap -p80 --script http-wordpress-brute --script-args 'userdb=testuser,passdb=passwordlist.txt' domain.com
```

Comment: Thank you for following up.  I viewed the link you provided, but I am still unclear as to how to implement scripts args.  For example of setting the path would it be something like:

nmap -p80 --script-arg http-form-brute.path --script-http-form-brute <target>

Comment: @CRYPTODOOM I had missed that you were having problems with that. I updated my answer.

Comment: Haha, man I had just figured it out and came back to update my post and saw that you had provided the answer.  I really appreciate the help, bonsaiviking!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this:

```
root@host:~# nmap --script-args="userdb=/usr/share/nmap/lists/users.txt,passdb=/usr/share/nmap/lists/passwords.txt" --script http-wordpress-brute -p80 domain.com
```